# alpakka, JMS and correlationId in jms.Message in response

Tags: scala, akka-stream, alpakka

I've used alpakka(Scala) and JMS connector for sending/receiving messages between client and server. All working perfect, but I don't know - how I can set correlationId in jms.Message in response. Any idea, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to set a correlationId in your JMS message when using Alpakka.
This is because the Alpakka Sink creates a text message and sends it to the broker as part of the same handler (see [code](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/master/jms/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/jms/JmsSinkStage.scala#L41)).

You can always open an issue [here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues) and explain your reasons. Pull requests for improvements are always welcome!

Comment: Thank you for answer,  Stefano. I've created issue have relation to this problem. https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/409